# How to make a sql in JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

How to make a sql  `SELECT count(*) from item_entrada where not isfinalizado` with JPA ?

```
`isfinalizado boolean DEFAULT false`
```

rows:

true
true
true
false

my expect result is 1 but i receive 3

my  code:

```
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        Root<ItensEntrada> rt = cq.from(ItensEntrada.class);
        cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        cq.where(rt.get("isfinalizado"));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use criteria for static queries. 2. You should use JPQL. 3. Both JPQL and Criteria don't use table and column names. They use entities and their properties. This is fundamental stuff.

Comment: Oh I wonder what SQL was generated for that by looking in the JPA providers log. You have done that, haven't you? Haven't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you are using not isfinalizado while in criteria query you are not checking for not condition.

I will suggest to use predicate in criteria query to achieve  that.